# Scraping a website with multiple pages and not getting the desired amount of output with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, pandas, loops, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape a website with multiple pages(50) and get specific information but when i run my code, my output is just 7 items when there are over 20000 on the website and I found out that my code is Scraping just the first page. Please I don't know what else to do, I'd appreciate your help. Thank you

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

name_selector = ".name"
old_price_selector = ".old"
new_price_selector = ".prc"

for i in range(1,50,1):
    url = "https://www.jumia.com.ng/phones-tablets/samsung/?q=samsung+phones&page=" +str(i)+ "#catalog-listing"
    website = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(website.content, 'html.parser')
    name = soup.select(name_selector)
    old_price = soup.select(old_price_selector)
    new_price = soup.select(new_price_selector)
    discount = soup.findAll("div", {"class": "bdg _dsct _sm"})

    data = []

    for names, old_prices, new_prices, discounts in zip(name, old_price, new_price, discount):
        dic = {"Phone Names": names.getText(),"New Prices": old_prices.getText(),"Old Prices": new_prices.getText(),"Discounts": discounts.getText()}
        data.append(dic)
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Comment: Maybe first use `print()` (and `print(type(...))`, `print(len(...))`, etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called `"print debuging"` and it helps to see what code is really doing.

Comment: you have to create `data = [ ]` before first `for`-loop. Your code create new `data = [ ]` in every loop and it removes previous content - and finally you get data only from last page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create `data = []` before first loop. That's all.

```
data = []

for i in range(1, 50):
    # ... code ...
```

Your code creates new `data = []` in every loop and it removes previous content - so you get data only from last page.